# Drawing a polygon with the given set of points

Tags: c#, .net

I've a large number of points. Now what I want to do is draw polygon connecting the outermost points,that is ,enclosing the other points. 
How do I do it.
Also is there any way to make a shaded polygon (eg like a heat map, dark in the centre and lighter as we move away from the centre).
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to draw a [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) or something else?

Comment: @Mike: It sounds like OP wants to find a convex hull, then compute a heatmap of point density inside it.

Comment: @Mike @Gabe Yes something of that sort only.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms for some help with a convex hull.

Comment: What graphical frontend? With or without hardware acceleration?

Comment: @Bobby I didn't get what you trying to say. Please elaborate.

Comment: @Olive: Are you using WinForms, WPF, DirectX, OpenGl etc. etc. etc. ...?