# Graham Scan algorithm for finding convex hull

Tags: c#, .net

Well this is not exactly a programming related question. But see if you people can help me on it.

I have to implement the graham scan algorithm for convex hull but the problem is I'm not able to find a pseudo code that gives all the info. I found some but they leave some points.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than that. What exactly is left out?

Comment: If this is an attempt to clarify [your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320896/drawing-a-polygon-with-the-given-set-of-points), it would be better to edit that original question, instead of posting an entirely new one. There's an "edit" link just under the tags that you can use to add new information or clarification to any of your posts at any time. Editing a question also "bumps" it up the list of recent questions.

Comment: Which point is missing in Wikipedia article's pseudocode? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan

Comment: Probably algorithm for how to calculate polar angles, etc.

Comment: But the algorithm description explains that: since we're starting with the lowermost point you can get away with ordering by cosine, which is just `x_diff / sqrt((x_diff * x_diff) + (y_diff * y_diff))`. In fact for ordering only you could use the square of this to save computing the sqrt, provided you copied over the sign of `x_diff` to the squared result.

Comment: no thats not the problem. in the loop i'm not getting where wud the final results of hull points wud be stored.. I'm referring to the wikepedia article.

Comment: http://softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0109/algorithm_0109.htm  another link to refer to. this helped me.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <stack> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
using namespace std; 
  
struct Point 
{ 
    int x, y; 
}; 
  
// A global point needed for  sorting points with reference 
// to  the first point Used in compare function of qsort() 
Point p0; 
  
// A utility function to find next to top in a stack 
Point nextToTop(stack<Point> &S) 
{ 
    Point p = S.top(); 
    S.pop(); 
    Point res = S.top(); 
    S.push(p); 
    return res; 
} 
  
// A utility function to swap two points 
int swap(Point &p1, Point &p2) 
{ 
    Point temp = p1; 
    p1 = p2; 
    p2 = temp; 
} 
  
// A utility function to return square of distance 
// between p1 and p2 
int distSq(Point p1, Point p2) 
{ 
    return (p1.x - p2.x)*(p1.x - p2.x) + 
          (p1.y - p2.y)*(p1.y - p2.y); 
} 
  
// To find orientation of ordered triplet (p, q, r). 
// The function returns following values 
// 0 --> p, q and r are colinear 
// 1 --> Clockwise 
// 2 --> Counterclockwise 
int orientation(Point p, Point q, Point r) 
{ 
    int val = (q.y - p.y) * (r.x - q.x) - 
              (q.x - p.x) * (r.y - q.y); 
  
    if (val == 0) return 0;  // colinear 
    return (val > 0)? 1: 2; // clock or counterclock wise 
} 
  
// A function used by library function qsort() to sort an array of 
// points with respect to the first point 
int compare(const void *vp1, const void *vp2) 
{ 
   Point *p1 = (Point *)vp1; 
   Point *p2 = (Point *)vp2; 
  
   // Find orientation 
   int o = orientation(p0, *p1, *p2); 
   if (o == 0) 
     return (distSq(p0, *p2) >= distSq(p0, *p1))? -1 : 1; 
  
   return (o == 2)? -1: 1; 
} 
  
// Prints convex hull of a set of n points. 
void convexHull(Point points[], int n) 
{ 
   // Find the bottommost point 
   int ymin = points[0].y, min = 0; 
   for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) 
   { 
     int y = points[i].y; 
  
     // Pick the bottom-most or chose the left 
     // most point in case of tie 
     if ((y < ymin) || (ymin == y && 
         points[i].x < points[min].x)) 
        ymin = points[i].y, min = i; 
   } 
  
   // Place the bottom-most point at first position 
   swap(points[0], points[min]); 
  
   // Sort n-1 points with respect to the first point. 
   // A point p1 comes before p2 in sorted output if p2 
   // has larger polar angle (in counterclockwise 
   // direction) than p1 
   p0 = points[0]; 
   qsort(&points[1], n-1, sizeof(Point), compare); 
  
   // If two or more points make same angle with p0, 
   // Remove all but the one that is farthest from p0 
   // Remember that, in above sorting, our criteria was 
   // to keep the farthest point at the end when more than 
   // one points have same angle. 
   int m = 1; // Initialize size of modified array 
   for (int i=1; i<n; i++) 
   { 
       // Keep removing i while angle of i and i+1 is same 
       // with respect to p0 
       while (i < n-1 && orientation(p0, points[i], 
                                    points[i+1]) == 0) 
          i++; 
  
  
       points[m] = points[i]; 
       m++;  // Update size of modified array 
   } 
  
   // If modified array of points has less than 3 points, 
   // convex hull is not possible 
   if (m < 3) return; 
  
   // Create an empty stack and push first three points 
   // to it. 
   stack<Point> S; 
   S.push(points[0]); 
   S.push(points[1]); 
   S.push(points[2]); 
  
   // Process remaining n-3 points 
   for (int i = 3; i < m; i++) 
   { 
      // Keep removing top while the angle formed by 
      // points next-to-top, top, and points[i] makes 
      // a non-left turn 
      while (orientation(nextToTop(S), S.top(), points[i]) != 2) 
         S.pop(); 
      S.push(points[i]); 
   } 
  
   // Now stack has the output points, print contents of stack 
   while (!S.empty()) 
   { 
       Point p = S.top(); 
       cout << "(" << p.x << ", " << p.y <<")" << endl; 
       S.pop(); 
   } 
} 
  
// Driver program to test above functions 
int main() 
{ 
    Point points[] = {{0, 3}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {4, 4}, 
                      {0, 0}, {1, 2}, {3, 1}, {3, 3}}; 
    int n = sizeof(points)/sizeof(points[0]); 
    convexHull(points, n); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here you have my implementation of graham algorithm in c++. Check it out: [graham algorithm](https://github.com/lukszar/Algorithms)

Comment: Let me know why I've got -1

Comment: Wasn't me, but I know some people here frown upon 'link only' answers: a StackOverflow answer can link to other sites for more information but it should be a complete answer in itself.

Answer (score -3):

I think you need this.
http://aduni.org/courses/algorithms/courseware/psets/Problem_Set_04.doc